# IDE-like inline diff highlighting in Vim

Tags: highlight, vimdiff, git, ide, version-control-systems

I enjoy using Vim and like it better than IDEs on most points. One common IDE feature that I miss, though, is inline diff highlighting:

[image: Changed lines highlighted in blue, new lines in green]
In this example changed lines are highlighted in blue and entirely new lines in green. Red for removed lines and beige for lines with changed whitespace are also common colorings. I know of tools that can show a diff in two windows, but is there any feature or plug-in that can do it like this? Preferably compared to version control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the [vim-gitgutter plugin](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter). If you're not using git, then [Signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) has a similar feature.

After installing vim-gitgutter, you can [switch the highlighting on and off](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#activation) with the following commands:

```
turn on with :GitGutterLineHighlightsEnable
turn off with :GitGutterLineHighlightsDisable
toggle with :GitGutterLineHighlightsToggle.
```

Or, to enable highlighting by default, [add the following line to your .vimrc](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#to-turn-on-line-highlighting-by-default):

```
let g:gitgutter_highlight_lines = 1
```

You can also [customize the colours used](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter#line-highlights) by [specifying the highlighting](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight) for the following groups:

```
GitGutterAddLine          " default: links to DiffAdd
GitGutterChangeLine       " default: links to DiffChange
GitGutterDeleteLine       " default: links to DiffDelete
GitGutterChangeDeleteLine
```